# Android Unparseable date Exception

Tags: java, android, date

I get a Unparseable date when trying to parse a Date string that is sent to my android client.

This is the exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-09-18T00:00:00Z" (at
>   offset 19) at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:571)

The date format my C# based backend sends (The C# object Property is **DateTime**):

> 2018-09-18T00:00:00Z

My Java Code where it fails:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
String targetDate = "2018-09-18T00:00:00Z";
Date date = dateFormat.parse(targetDate));
```

How can I change my code to parse the exact format sent by the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format sent by your backend follows ISO-8601 instant format.

You can use `LocalDate.parse(targetDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT)` to parse it.

LocalDate supports only SDK 26+, android 8 and higher

Comment: You should add a notice, that `LocalDate` is only available in java 8 and later

Answer (score 7):

You have to change the format String to:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatParse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
String targetDate = "2018-09-18T00:00:00Z";
Date dateString = dateFormatParse.parse(targetDate));
```

Comment: Ooops major blunder on my part. I need to parse the string to Java Date format not String. Sorry about that. Edited question