# How to parse 2019-02-17T18:39:03?

Tags: android, date-parsing

I looking for a solution to parse the String date.

```
 datestring.add("2019-02-17T18:39:02");
 datestring.add("2019-02-17T18:39:01");
 datestring.add("2019-02-17T18:39:03");
 datestring.add("2019-02-17T18:39:07");
```

datastring is the ArrayList of String date.

```
  Collections.sort(datestring, new Comparator<String>() {
        DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a");

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            try {
                return f.parse(o1).compareTo(f.parse(o2));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

So here i am trying to sort the list based on date.
But I am getting ParseException:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-02-17T18:39:07"
```

Comment: These are the values actually I am getting from backend service. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: your incoming date is in format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss` try using this format to parse your date

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35389674/5110595)

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your incoming date is in format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss` and the format you are using is `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a` which will not generate error.

Try parsing your incoming date string using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss` and then convert it to some other format if you want.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    List<String> datestring = new ArrayList<String>();

    datestring.add("2019-02-17T18:39:02");
    datestring.add("2019-02-17T18:39:01");
    datestring.add("2019-02-17T18:39:03");
    datestring.add("2019-02-17T18:39:07");

    Collections.sort(datestring, Comparator.comparing(LocalDateTime::parse));
    System.out.println(datestring);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> [2019-02-17T18:39:01, 2019-02-17T18:39:02, 2019-02-17T18:39:03, 2019-02-17T18:39:07]

Your strings are in ISO 8601 format, the international standard for date and time format. `LocalDateTime` and the other classes of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, parse (and print) ISO 8601 format as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

`Comparator.comparing` was introduced in Java 8 and accepts a lambda or as (as here) a method reference. If you can use it on your API level, the advantage is not only that it’s brief, but even more that it is hard to get wrong.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Guide to Java 8 Comparator.comparing()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing)